# Angular component not loading data from service

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to load some data from a service, the service works as i tested it in the console, it displays the wanted array properly, but when calling the same method of the service from my component (where i need to render the data) it just displays [object Object].... in the console and nothing on the component itself.

**FYI** : the provider ('/api/departement') that am using works properly since the data can be displayed in the console (data from the service itself).

here's my code :

**Department.ts :**

```
export class Departement{
public code_dep:String;
public lib_dep_AR:String;
public lib_dep_FR:String;
public countm:number;
}
```

**Departement.service.ts**

```
import { Departement}  from './departement';
import { Http,Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class DepartementService{

constructor(private http:Http){}
private headers = new Headers({'Content-type':'application/json'});
private depUrl = '/api/departement';

getAllDeps():Promise<Departement[]>{

    return this.http.get(this.depUrl + "/allDeparts").toPromise().
    then(response=>response.json() as Departement[]);  

  }
// etc
}
```

**displaying.component.ts**

```
  export class Displaying implements OnInit {
  departements:Departement[];
  departement:Departement;
  constructor(public depserv:DepartementService,public router:Router) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.depserv.getAllDeps().then(dep =>    
      {    this.departements = dep;
       });

    //etc  
  }
```

where i want to render the result

```html
<select name="budget" >     
 <option>my results down here</option>            
 <option *ngFor="let x of departements">{{x.lib_dep_FR}}</option>
</select>
```

**fixed by moving on to the Observable interface**

**Department.service.ts**

```
private extractData(res:Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || [];
}
getData():Observable<Departement[]>{
    return this.http.get(this.depUrl+"/allDeparts").map(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**catching up the result in the displaying.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.depserv.getData().subscribe(
   dept => this.departements = dept);
}
```

Comment: what does console.log(this.deparments) show inside component

Comment: it shows "undefined" :( @Sajeetharan

Comment: and when i try
this.depserv.getAllDeps().then(Departement =>    
      {    this.departements = Departement;
        console.log("data : "+Departement);
       });
it shows data : [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: add JSON.stringify(console.log(this.deparments)); and post the resul

Comment: same result ,undefined

Comment: are you getting data in dep ??

Comment: @RakeshAR am getting : data : [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Answer (score 0):

In `displaying.component.ts` file instead of this  `this.departements = dep;`  change to this `this.departements = dep.json();` and just check what you are getting   in `console.log(this.departements)` If you are getting array of objects or array of values then data will come for `x.lib_dep_FR`

Comment: the .getAllDeps() method is already returning an array "Promise : Department[]" , so i can't use dep.json() while fetching in the component

Comment: In displaying.component.ts file are you getting data in dep ??

Comment: yes am getting : data : [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: @YassineBenHamida above you told you are getting undefined

Comment: Because you don't have JSON. You have an array: []. JSON is a string representation of a javascript object.

You could use the JSON.stringify method to generate a JSON string from an existing object:  . change to this.departements =JSON.stringify(dep);  and now check what you are getting in console.log( this.departements)